# How to get the target of a weak reference in a safe way

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, weak-references

Consider this code:

```
var weakRef = new WeakReference(new StringBuilder("Mehran"));
if (weakRef.IsAlive)
{
    // Garbage Collection might happen.
    Console.WriteLine((weakRef.Target as StringBuilder).ToString());
}
```

It's possible for `GC.Collect` to run after checking `weakRef.IsAlive` and before using the `weakRef.Target`.

Am I wrong with this? If it's possible, ss there a safe way to do that?

For example an API like `weakRef.GetTargetIfIsAlive()` would be appropriate.

Comment: Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms404247.aspx

Comment: You should first cast to a strong reference and then check for `null`. There´s no way you can assure your strong reference will not be null beforehand.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That API already exists; `weakRef.Target` returns `null` if the object has already been garbage collected.

```
StringBuilder sb = weakRef.Target as StringBuilder;
if (sb != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 11):

The `IsAlive` property does not exist for the benefit of code which will want to use the target if it is alive, but rather for the benefit of code which wants to find out if the target has died but wouldn't be interested in accessing it in any case.  If code were to test `Target` against null, that would cause `Target` to momentarily have a strong rooted reference (the code that's testing against null), and it's possible that the act of generating such a rooted reference might prevent the object from being garbage-collected when it otherwise would be.  If the code isn't interested in `Target` except to find out whether it has yet been invalidated, there's no reason for code to get the reference.  It can simply test `IsAlive` instead, and take suitable action if it returns `false`.

Comment: I was wondering why `IsAlive` exists.  This is a very clever answer, Thanks.

Comment: @mehrandvd: It's not hard to imagine a concurrent GC where the act of fetching the `Target` from a `WeakReference` would prevent that object from getting collected in the next cycle *even if the reference was immediately discarded*.  On such a system, code which wanted to take some action as soon as an object was no longer needed and used `Target` rather than `IsAlive` could end up keeping the object in question alive forever.

Answer (score 1):

Take a local copy of the target and check for null.

`WeakReference.Target` will return `null` if the target has been collected but you're concern is that it's collected between your `.IsAlive` check and getting the target.

```
var weakRef = new WeakReference(new StringBuilder("Mehran"));

if (weakRef.IsAlive)
{
    var stringBuilder = weakRef.Target as StringBuilder;

    if (stringBuilder != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(stringBuilder.ToString());
    }
}
```

`Console.WriteLine((weakRef.Target as StringBuilder).ToString());` will throw a null reference exception if the cast fails.

Comment: I was wondering why checking `weakRef.IsAlive` is required, @supercat answered the question, so I think checking it is not necessary.

Comment: @mehrandvd It might not be necessary, I only used it in this example as it was based upon your original question. It can't do any harm to use it but yes it is possibly a pointless check given the `as` cast and null check on `.Target`.

Comment: @TrevorPilley: Using `IsAlive` on a `WeakReference` if a `true` value would mean one wants to retrieve the target is pointless.  It's possible that with some garbage collectors, using `if (wr1.IsAlive && wr2.IsAlive && wr3.IsAlive) {Foo wt1 = wr1.Target as Foo, wt2 = wr2.Target as Foo, wt3 = wr3.Target as Foo; if (wr1 != null && wr2 != null && wr3 != null) {... use all three things...}` might be helpful if e.g. a concurrent garbage-collector worked by keeping track of whether a reference to something had been created since the last GC. On such a GC, if wr3 had died but wr1 and wr2 was alive...

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is `TryGetValue`. Your code should look like:

```
var weakRef = new WeakReference(new StringBuilder("Mehran"));
if (weakRef.TryGetValue(out StringBuilder sb)
{
    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
}
```